# Unable to stream image from midlet to browser?

Tags: java-me

My midlet acts as server , when i request any resource from midlet it must  transferred to browser and displayed. Here i am able to transfer html files,but i am unable to transfer image through OutputStream. I am converting image to byte array also.

Comment: @Satish Can you post some of the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit light on detail here!  I assume:

- you have converted your J2ME `Image` to an `int[]` using `Image.getRGB()`
- you are successfully sending the `int` array to wherever it needs to go, through your output stream (for example, by iterating through each `int` in the array, and sending it using `DataOutput.writeInt()`)
- you are successfully reconstructing this array at the server end
- you are having difficulty converting the data back to an image at the server end

One way of doing this is to use `BufferedImage` on the server.  You'll need to send the image's width and height to the server, along with the `int` array.

Then create a `BufferedImage` as follows:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
img.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, intArray, 0, width);
```

HTH.